# Align boxes in items using \setlist and enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, box

**Problem:**

I have managed to vertical-center align boxes with definitions using `\setlist` with `enumerate`. I wish to change so that the top of each box is aligned with the top of each definition.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Material Colors
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{MaterialsCoral}{cmyk}{0, 0.75, 0.5, 0}
\definecolor{MaterialsSky}{cmyk}{0.6, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{MaterialsSun}{cmyk}{0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.05}
\definecolor{MaterialsGrass}{cmyk}{0.65, 0, 0.3, 0}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\specialitem}[3][white]{%
  \item[%
    \colorbox{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{\makebox[2em]{\strut #3}}}%
  ]
}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=12mm}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=6pt]
  \specialitem{MaterialsCoral}{\textbf{H}} \textcolor{MaterialsCoral}{\textbf{Hyper}} \lipsum[2]
  \specialitem{MaterialsSky}{\textbf{T}} \textcolor{MaterialsSky}{\textbf{Text}} \lipsum[2]  
  \specialitem{MaterialsGrass}{\textbf{M}} \textcolor{MaterialsGrass}{\textbf{Markup}} \lipsum[2]
  \specialitem{MaterialsSun}{\textbf{L}} \textcolor{MaterialsSun}{\textbf{Language}} \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Desired outcome:**

The top of each box should be moved down to align with each definition.

Comment: You want to align the top of the coloured box, not the top of the letter inside??

Comment: @Bernard Correct, the letter inside should be centered as it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is is a small modification of the code that works with `\raisebox`. Of course, the value of the negative raising might have to be adjusted for another font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Material Colors
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{MaterialsCoral}{cmyk}{0, 0.75, 0.5, 0}
\definecolor{MaterialsSky}{cmyk}{0.6, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{MaterialsSun}{cmyk}{0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.05}
\definecolor{MaterialsGrass}{cmyk}{0.65, 0, 0.3, 0}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\specialitem}[3][white]{%
  \item[%
\smash{\raisebox{-1.06ex}{\colorbox{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{\makebox[2em]{\strut #3}}}}}%
  ]
}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=12mm}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=6pt]
  \specialitem{MaterialsCoral}{\textbf{H}} \textcolor{MaterialsCoral}{\textbf{Hyper}} \lipsum[2]
  \specialitem{MaterialsSky}{\textbf{T}} \textcolor{MaterialsSky}{\textbf{Text}} \lipsum[2]
  \specialitem{MaterialsGrass}{\textbf{M}} \textcolor{MaterialsGrass}{\textbf{Markup}} \lipsum[2]
  \specialitem{MaterialsSun}{\textbf{L}} \textcolor{MaterialsSun}{\textbf{Language}} \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]